# How do I deduplicate -exec expressions in a find command?

Tags: shell-script, grep, find

I have a `find` command that searches multiple file types using `grep`. For example, if want to search `.js` and `.jsx` files for the string `foo`, while excluding the `dist` directory, I'd type:

```
find . -path "./dist" -prune -or -iname "*.js" -exec grep "foo" {} + -or -iname "*.jsx" -exec grep "foo" {} +
```

Is there a way to rewrite this command so that the `-exec` isn't duplicated for each file type? I tried

```
find . -path "./dist" -prune -or -iname "*.js" -or -iname "*.jsx" -exec grep "foo" {} +
```

but all that searched just the `.jsx` files, not both `.js` and `.jsx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-or` has lower precedence than `-and` (which is the default connector), so you need to explicitly increase your disjunction’s “priority”:

```
find . -path "./dist" -prune -or \( -iname "*.js" -or -iname "*.jsx" \) -exec grep "foo" {} +
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick! I was looking at the find man page, but I didn't notice that `-or` had a different precedence than `-and`.

Comment: note that the parentheses `(` and `)` are escaped here so they're not picked up by the shell